# CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources after adding Google Play Games

Tags: android, facebook, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

Help! After I plugin Google Play Games, I can't build an apk anymore.
I'm using Facebook sdk.

CommandInvokationFailure: Failed to re-package resources.

```
C:\Android\android-sdk\build-tools\24.0.0\aapt.exe package --auto-add-overlay -v -f -m -J gen -M AndroidManifest.xml -S "res" -I "C:/Android/android-sdk\platforms\android-25\android.jar" -F bin/resources.ap_ --extra-packages android.support.v7.appcompat:android.support.v7.cardview:com.facebook:com.facebook.android:com.google.example.games.mainlibproj:com.unity3d.player:com.google.android.gms.ads.impl:com.google.android.gms.ads:com.google.android.gms.auth.api:com.google.android.gms.auth:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms.base:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms:com.google.android.gms.drive:com.google.android.gms.games:com.google.android.gms.nearby:com.google.android.gms.tasks:android.support.v4:android.support.v4:com.TeratomoCorp.PanicChase:com.unity3d.ads.android -S
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to delete all the .aar files from plugin folder and then build it again and it will work fine.

keep the backup before doing anything in the project.